# Install Android NDK without SDK manager in ubuntu

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

How to install Android NDK without SDK manager through ubuntu command line, there is no option i found to install through command line. I got this error during building gradle build in offline mode.

I struck in error org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException NDK is not configure. Download it with SDK manager. preferred NDK version is '21.4.7075529'

Comment: Can't you just download it from the NDK download page?

Comment: I did download Android-NDK from here https://developer.android.com/ndk , but some when i compile with ./gradlew build it throw error:

org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException NDK is not configure. Download it with SDK manager. preferred NDK version is '21.4.7075529'

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line SDK manager: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager

If you're using AGP you should let that manage the NDK. You're otherwise just doing exactly the same thing by hand. You would need to install the NDK to the correct location in the SDK, and doing it by hand is just an opportunity to make a mistake.